# How to create a NSWindow inside a menulet

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nsmenuitem, nsstatusitem

I'm creating a menulet application in Xcode 4, and I'm trying to figure out how to display a window that will appear when the menulet icon is clicked. I would hope for the window to be displayed as the normal NSWindow.

I have looked at the MAAttatchedWindow source code, and that doesn't seem to help me at all. Could someone please explain how to make a menulet drop-down a window when clicked?

I believe I'm supposed to use the setView: function to create a custom view for the NSStatusItem, but can't quite figure out how to code should be layed out. I have this so far:

```
  -(void)awakeFromNib {
statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar]
              statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength]retain];
[statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
[statusItem setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", 0x24DC]];
[statusItem setEnabled:YES];
[statusItem setView:(NSView *)
```

how to I get the MAAttachedWindow to display as an NSView?

Comment: If you want the window to look like a regular window, then why not use a regular window? Otherwise, what do you mean by “be displayed as the normal NSWindow”?

Comment: well the thing is, I don't know how to make the NSStatusItem display a drop down window

Comment: You said you want it to “be displayed as the normal NSWindow”. What do you mean by that?

Comment: Also, your code sample is incomplete. You cut it off at a cast.